# Flexbox items are overlapping z-index set on sibling elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox, z-index

I have a flexbox with multiple children in it. Each `flex-item` has a child element that is being overlapped by the next sibling `flex-item`. How do you correct or account for this behavior?

Here is a demo of the behavior in question. There were several other questions on SO that suggested applying a greater z-index to the `:first-child` in the group. This worked - but only for the first element.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  background: #eee;
  margin-top: 5%;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.container .flex-item {
  _flex: 0 0 1;
  width: 25%;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  background: #ccc;
  z-index: 500;
}

.container .flex-item .widget {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #004990;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -35px;
  right: -35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="widget"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="widget"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="widget"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="widget"></div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

I have a codepen that exemplifies the desired functionality https://codepen.io/barrychapman/pen/QWKLbKw - but the only way I could get it to work was to apply sequentially decreasing `z-index`'s on each element in the list.

How can I achieve this desired behavior without the need for the codepen example?

Comment: Do you want to confined the `widget` ( blue circle) inside the `flex-item` ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the other questions tagged. This is regarding child elements of a flex that overlap EACH OTHER.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just remove the `z-index` from every item except the widgets bubbles. This will lead to the desired output of having the bubbles always on top of any container.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  background: #eee;
  margin-top: 5%;
  height: 100px;
}

.container .flex-item {
  flex: 0 0 1;
  width: 25%;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  background: #ccc;
}

.container .flex-item .widget {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #004990;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -35px;
  right: -35px;
  z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="widget"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="widget"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="widget"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="widget"></div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: perfect! I do not really know how I butchered that. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

i may have not understood the question correctly.

But if you remove z-index from all elements and just add `z-index : 1` only on `.widget` element, then you will achieve same thing as that codepen.

https://codepen.io/barrychapman/pen/QWKLbKw

```
.widget {
 z-index: 1;
}
```